# Asp.net sql cache dependency programmatically configuration

Tags: asp.net, caching, web-config, sqlcachedependency

I've a question regarding SqlCacheDependency configuration. Every resource I've read requires the developer to define the polled databases into web.config.
This is not a good scenario for our application that connects to different databases, because we don't want to edit web.config each time we add / remove a database.

We tried to configure it using SqlCacheDependency and SqlCacheDependencyAdmin in application startup but it seems that you must anyway configure everything in web.config.

Do you know a possible solution?
Thanks,
Marco

Comment: I've been trying to work out how to answer this question but I'm not sure I understand your scenario correctly - can you add some more detail? Your application uses multiple databases - do you let your uses enter a connection string, or do you have multiple connection strings defined in your web.config?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your interest into my issue. I've just one connection string changed at runtime based on username. Each user has a different db.
thanks,
Marco

Comment: Marco - I'm trying to do this now, have you figured out anything yet?  I have a connection string which holds a variable that we replace - I can't change this, hoping I can somehow set this up.  Thanks!

Comment: No, sorry Neil :-( I've given up on this !